# matlab with symbol, how can I shorten numbers?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

```
syms w
A=[141432432 23432*w; 31432*w 3543566]
B=[13432*w^2 ; 3424324]
```

which returns

```
A =
[ 141432432, 23432*w]
[   31432*w, 3543566]

B =
 13432*w^2
   3424324
```

Then

```
C=A\B
c1=C(1)
simplify(c1)
```

returns

```
C =
 -(w*(2974823657*w - 5014922498))/(2*(23016082*w^2 - 15661723666641))
    (2*(6596791*w^3 - 7567351113687))/(23016082*w^2 - 15661723666641)

c1 =
-(w*(2974823657*w - 5014922498))/(2*(23016082*w^2 - 15661723666641))

ans =
-(w*(2974823657*w - 5014922498))/(2*(23016082*w^2 - 15661723666641))
```

I want to simplify `c1` to something like this,

```
c1 = -(w*(3*e^9*w-5.01*e^9))/......
```

How can I do this? When I do not use `syms` variables, the numbers looks good. But, if I use this, the formula look so dirty.

Answer (score 2):

It may look "dirty," but that's the point of symbolic math – it's accurate to the full precision of your original input. If you want a result in decimal format you should be aware that it will necessarily be less precise unless the values can be represented exactly as a (sufficiently short) finite decimal expansion. In Matlab's Symbolic Math toolbox, you can simply use the [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) function to convert your result to [variable precision arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/precision-control.html):

```
syms w;
c1 = -(w*(2974823657*w - 5014922498))/(2*(23016082*w^2 - 15661723666641));
vpa(c1)
```

which returns

```
-(1.0*w*(2974823657.0*w - 5014922498.0))/(46032164.0*w^2 - 31323447333282.0)
```

This doesn't help you much in this case. If you want a lot less precision, as suggested in your question, you can use [`digits`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html) or the second argument to `vpa`:

```
syms w;
c1 = -(w*(2974823657*w - 5014922498))/(2*(23016082*w^2 - 15661723666641));
vpa(c1,3) % default value is 32
```

which now returns the much less precise

```
-(1.0*w*(2.97e9*w - 5.01e9))/(4.6e7*w^2 - 3.13e13)
```

Lastly, you can also convert your symbolic expression to a floating point function using the unfortunately-named [`matlabFunction`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html):

```
syms w;
c1 = -(w*(2974823657*w - 5014922498))/(2*(23016082*w^2 - 15661723666641));
c1_fun = matlabFunction(c1)
```

which returns the [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)

```
c1_fun =

    @(w)-(w.*(w.*2.974823657e9-5.014922498e9))./(w.^2.*4.6032164e7-3.1323447333282e13)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I wanted. I think I have to use this method in exam. Because I can't write all numbers in paper.